# Can't fix a menu connected to a slider on Drupal

Tags: drupal, menu, slider

So I'm encountering an issue with Drupal, it's already a set website, a friend's just asking help in.

The Packing Tips works fine which can be found here:
http://www.locnstor247.com/tips/packing-tips

But for storage tips, here: http://www.locnstor247.com/tips/storage-tips
The sidebar menu's not tying up with the actual content.

Maybe someone on here already knows how this works! Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could pose your question with more of a technical focus? E.g. if you suspect this to be a bug, give bit more background on how the sidebar is being rendered? Is it custom code or a plugin?

Comment: It seems like a plugin. Checking around, I suspect it has something to do with the links on the sidebar, but not really sure what it is yet.

Comment: I will downvote myself because I have found the solution!!! Apparently the person who coded it in hard coded the div menu IDs in the javascript.